# SharePoint REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api

In list A I have column test I'd and Testdepartment.
Testdepartment is a look column to ListA 
Testdepartment is present in  ListB

Values in the column are as below:

Test ID   Test department

1         A

1         B

1         C

1         D

2        E

```
endPointUrl ="/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle ('List A')/Items?$select=Test I'd, Testdepart ment/Title&$expand=Testdepartment/I'd";
```

I am using the below code to extract the Test department value based on the test I'd

```
getdatafrom(endPointUrl).done(function(){
   Var len = data.d.results.length;
   for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      Var x=data.d.results[i].Testdepartment.Title;
   }
});
```

But the above code returns only the last element of the array i.e., D on selection of TestID as 1 .

I want the code to return all the Testdepartment associated with the Specific TestID so that I can put it as a filter for another endpointurl.

```
endPointUrl2="/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle ('List B')/Items?$select=Title, Testdepart &$filter=Title eq"+x;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Testdepartment is getting overwritten in the for loop.
Just create an array of x and store all the values of Testdepartment as below:

```
getdatafrom(endPointUrl).done(function(){
   Var len = data.d.results.length;
   var x = [];
   for(i=0;i<len;i++){
      x.push(data.d.results[i].Testdepartment.Title);
   }
});
```

Comment: How can I split the value  of x .For ex Title eq 'A' or Title eq 'B'

Comment: You could simply use a foreach loop:
'x.forEach(function(title) {
    console.log(title);
});'